# When to Use Normal Approximation?

Tags: statistics

**Do we use normal approximation when discrete distributions are hard to solve?**

For example, $P(X\ge 7000)$ where is $X\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(13000, 0.7)$.

Obviously, summing each case manually cannot be done and the summation is difficult to solve (I assume)?

In my textbook, sometimes when something is a dicrete distribution and I calculate it using discrete distribution, I flip to the answer and they used normal approximation to the discrete distribution.

**Example:**

[image]

"Why are you choosing to use normal approximation?!"

Comment: Are you wondering about why an approximation in the first place or why the normal approximation?

Comment: @user190080  Why an approximation in the first place? I know they used normal approximation because binomial distribution is approximately normal in the long-run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you readily point out, it is a matter of convenience. You can indeed evaluate the binomial distribution $n$ times and the add the results together, but that gets pretty boring really fast. Unless of course you have a computational tool at hand (calculator, computer, $\dots$)

Instead if $n$ is *large enough* you can use the Normal approximation and the results are strikingly good. The problem is always *"what does it mean for $n$ to be large?"*. And to that there are a few rules you could follow (these are more suggestions that actual rules)

- Both $np\gtrsim 5 $ and $n(1-p)\gtrsim 5$
- The $|\gamma| < 1/3$ and $n > 5$, with $\gamma$ being the skewness

$$
\gamma = {\frac {1-2p}{\sqrt {np(1-p)}}}
$$

I am pretty sure that there are more rules out there, but these have worked out for me in the past